# How to use scopeDescriptor and subjectTypes in VSTS Graph api groups list query?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to resolve a particular VSTS group by name to retrieve the identityDescriptor property. Rather than query all groups and filter, I want to leverage the query parameters supported. Looking at [VSTS Groups - List API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/graph/groups/list), it supports the additional query parameters scopeDescriptor, and subjectType.  However, I keep providing bad values for these parameters.

However, when I specify any combination of these I get 0 results. In addition, as soon as I add a scopeDescriptor, I hit an Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Graph.InvalidSubjectTypeException -> HTTP 400 Bad Request.

Questions:

1. What are examples of expected values for subjectTypes?

**Edit 1**
subjectTypes are not the actual type, but the subtype that prefixes the subject descriptor.  For example -> vssgp,aadgp:

```
"subjectDescriptor": "vssgp.Dc0NDgzLTzQ1NwOTI5LTI0NTcwNDLTAtMwUy0xLTktMTAtMC0wMjgxNjcxNDU0OS0zMU1MTM3NDI0NS0yMjUzNzA0ODMtE"
```

2. What are examples of expected values for scopeDescriptor?

Example query urls:

```
 - Working:
   https://{account}.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/graph/groups?api-version=4.1-preview.1

 - Working subjectTypes:
   https://{account}.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/graph/groups?subjectTypes=vssgp&api-version=4.1-preview.1

 - scopeDescriptor throws:
   https://{account}.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/graph/groups?scopeDescriptor=collection&api-version=4.1-preview.1
   https://{account}.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/graph/groups?scopeDescriptor=collection&subjectTypes=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity&api-version=4.1-preview.1
```

Answer (score 8):

You can get the scope descriptors for a project or a collection by making an api request to `https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/descriptors/{Id}`(replace id with projectId if you want to get the scope descriptor for a project and so on).

For example if you want to get the scope descriptor for a project then simply replace the storage key in the request URL with the project Id and in response you get the scope descriptor. The scope descriptor has the following format scp.(long unique identifier).

P.S: More on how to get descriptors can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/descriptors/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0. Remember storagekey can be substituted with projectid or collectionid to get specific descriptors.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21663013)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will keep that in mind the next time I post any answers. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Regarding subjectTypes, it is the group type, such as vssgp, aadgp, you can get it from descriptor value of each group.

Comment: Thank you!  The documentation is pretty confusing in how it describes the subject types.  After filtering to vssgp, it's filtered the return groups.  That said, I still can't figure out what scopeDescriptor values should be.

Comment: Also, sorry, I don't have enough rep to mark as answer.