# How to check when user was added to team/group in Azure DevOps via API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am new to Azure DevOps. I want to check when particular user was added to a group/team via REST API. I referred to the documentations, but could find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that there is **no** such Rest API to get the time when a user joins a group or team.

**For workaround:**

The date and operation will be recorded in `Organization Settings -> Auditing -> Logs`.

[image]

You could **export** the Auditing log and search the opearation in it.

This method has limitations, you can only view logs within **90 days**. Therefore, you need to export the log regularly to ensure that you will not miss some records.

On the other hand, the requirement makes sense. You could submit a suggestion ticket about this feature in [our UserVoice website](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html).

[image]

**Update:**

> Is there any way to get all of the groups on project level ?

Here is my rest api sample:

```
https://vssps.dev.azure.com/Organizationname/_apis/graph/groups?scopeDescriptor=xxx&api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

[image]

Get scopeDescriptor:

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/descriptors/{ProjectID}?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

[image]

Comment: Nice to know that. Is there any way to get all of the groups on project level ?

Comment: @Baequiraheal Of course. You could use this [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1):  `https://vssps.dev.azure.com/Organizationname/_apis/graph/groups?scopeDescriptor=xxx&api-version=5.1-preview.1`  You may be confused about scopeDescriptor. If yes, you could refer to this ticket:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50165145/how-to-use-scopedescriptor-and-subjecttypes-in-vsts-graph-api-groups-list-query

Comment: Do you mean that you couldn't run this rest api successfully?  This rest api could get the groups from the particular project. Please check if it could meet your requirements. I have updated my steps in the answer. you could refer to it.

Comment: These api calls are wrapped in PowerShell functions in the AzurePipelinesPS module:
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzurePipelinesPS